# How does spark saveAsTable work while reading and writing to hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I have the following code:

```
Dataset<Row> rows = sparkContext.sql ("select from hive tables with multiple joins");
rows.saveAsTable(writing to another external table in hive immediately);
```

1) In the above case when `saveAsTable()` is invoked, will spark load the whole dataset into memory?

1.1) If yes, then how do we handle the scenario when this query can actually return huge volume of data which cannot fit into the memory?

2) When spark starts executing `saveAsTable()` to write data to the external Hive table when the server crashes, is there a possibility of partial data be written to the target Hive table?

2.2) If yes, how do we avoid incomplete/partial data being persisted into target hive tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes spark will place all data in memory but use parallel processes. But when we write data it will use driver memory to store the data before write. So try increasing driver memory.

so there are couple of options you have. If you have memory in clustor you can increase num-cores, num-executors, executor-memory  along with driver-memory based on data size.

If you cannot fit all data in memory break the data and process in a loop  programatically.

Lets say source data is partitioned by date and you have 10 days to process. try to process 1 day at a time and write to a staging dataframe. Then create partition based on date in final table and overwrite date everytime in loop.

Comment: Hi,

Will spark not load the data onto disk if it cannot fit into memory?   (cases where we fetch from hive table and insert into another hive table)

For example, If we use a createTempView and explicitly define it as IN MEMORY, I agree that it will all be in memory.  

Thank you

Comment: Thats right.  Default persist level of a dataframe is Disk and Memory. But if you want to cache / Disk only persist that will expect all data to fit in memory.